# npm start run error "var before = prev.prev || {}; TypeError: Cannot read property 'prev' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-start

Currently I am trying to run a very basic to do list using node. After setting up package.json and server.js, I ran npm start run, but I am getting a weird error.

UPDATE:
Here is the basic code and .json file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ynPL.png)

> var express = require('express'),
>       app = express(),
>       port =process.env.PORT ||3000;
>
> app.listen(port);
>
> console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port);

This is the error:
[image]

This is the complete log page:
[image]

Comment: It's very hard to figure out what the problem is with your code if you don't post the code.

Comment: updated the post and included a picture

Comment: @EjminMehranian An image of the code is not search friendly, aside from other problems.  Post the code.  Not an image of it.

Comment: No, don't post pictures of code, post the actual code

Comment: I mean its 4 lines of code lol.Anyways I included the code as well.

Comment: Seeing this same package error via jest

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with nodemon when running my test scripts in a node.js api.

It seems the error is related to this issue with nanomatch, a package nodemon uses, a link to the issue: https://github.com/micromatch/nanomatch/issues/15.

I solved it with the following steps:

1. Verify the version of nanomatch in node_modules/nanomatch/package.json if the version is 1.2.11 (I also had a similar issue with 1.2.9) you need to change its version.
2. Run npm i nanomatch@1.2.13 (--save or --save-dev according to your situation)

After these steps nodemon worked for me. Hope that helps.